# How not to use any custom theme, and use the default system theme

Tags: android

I did not want to change the colours and wanted to use the default system theme. When I removed all the entries in the themes.xml files that AS generated, it looked like the first image below on the Android 12 emulator. But I also wanted to remove the ActionBar. When I changed the "parent" of the style from "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" to "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar", it became purple like the second image below.

I am not sure how I can know the system's default theme, but judging by the system menu (third image below), it seems the theme colour blue + black. Then why does the NoActionBar theme get purple? Is what I did the correct way to "not use any custom theme, and use the system's theme as it is"?

[image] [image]

[image]

Manifest

```
<application ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DeleteAndroid">
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.DeleteAndroid" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: What you appear to be referring to are the Material You colors available on some Android 12+ devices (<0.1% of the Android device ecosystem as of December 2021). See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#material-you for more. Beyond that, you are welcome to use `Theme.DeviceDefault`-based themes, which are literally the "default system theme", but you may not like the results, nor the testing burden.

Comment: Since the Android 12 emulator did not seem to respond to the wallpaper colour changes, I tested it with a real device running on Google's stock Android 12. First, `Theme.DeviceDefault` does not seem to exist. AS did not show it in the auto-complete, and compilation failed with "not found". I have tried some of other themes in the auto-complete, but none of them showed the system colour (so-called "Material You") for the button. I have not many apps on the phone but Google Calculator app seems to show buttons in the system colour, and it does not have an ActionBar. What theme is it using?

Comment: "What theme is it using?" -- one that we do not have access to, AFAIK. And, again, that's an Android 12 thing. "First, Theme.DeviceDefault does not seem to exist" -- yes, it does. It is a framework theme, not a library theme, and so you reference it as `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault`. There are sub-themes (e.g., `Theme.DeviceDefault.DayNight`) as well. It is not commonly used, as its implementation varies by device -- its primary role is for device manufacturers and the firms that they hire to write apps for them that get pre-installed.